# host my website on my local pc

Tags: windows, iis, web-hosting

I want host my website on my local pc (Windows).

I turn on IIS, and for now I have simple html under `c:\windown\inetpub\wwroot`

I also added:

`127.0.0.1 mywebsite.com` in host file.

I can access the website from my local network, but not from outside of it.

How can I expose it to the world?

Comment: Generally speaking, it's a really bad idea to host a WAN accessible site on a PC that isn't configured solely as a server, as Windows PC versions aren't configured, or intended, for that use case. It creates a massive data security issue if the webserver is set up on a PC used for normal usage from a multitude of angles - Windows users don't generally have locked down accounts on their personal PCs, so privilege escalation attacks become a primary concern, the Windows Firewall is not configured for WAN access, and it's complicated to setup if someone has never done so before. etc. _cont'd..._

Comment: _Cont'd..._ It's best to use an actual server OS for hosting a WAN side webserver, as they're configured for that use case, whereas consumer versions of Windows are not _([TrueNAS Core](https://www.truenas.com) is a free BSD server OS and supports jails, VMs, and Docker images, and is relatively easy to get set up - you'd set up a WAN accessible webserver within one of those three)_

Comment: While its a bad idea, many of us had similar thoughts. I  would use a cheap NAS box to run it on. There are two issues. You need to forward port 80 to your pc, on tbe router  And run a dyndns like service to make your dynamic ipaddress public.

Comment: @JW0914 That's and old pc, I don't use it anymore. Ipaid a lot on web hosting, so I was thinking to save that money, and to host my website by myself.

Comment: @3SAT It would still be recommended to run a server OS, not a Windows consumer edition, as it's unlikely you're going to be able to secure a consumer Windows edition enough, and privilege escalation attacks endanger all other devices on your network. [TrueNAS](https://www.truenas.com/truenas-core/) requires a lot of RAM, but only because of file sharing due to the ZFS filesystem, and you can likely run it to host a website just fine with ~8GB - 16GB of RAM _(this is what I would try first since everything's built-in)_; another option would be [Ubuntu Server](https://ubuntu.com/download/server)